# When launching PhraseExpress it can't find a procedure?

Tags: troubleshooting, windows-8-preview

When I launch [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/) I get an error `The specified procedure could not be found` with `Test` as the title of that error dialog. The same happens with the USB edition...

This sounds like a quite generic error as just searching for it tells me that it is some kind of linking problem, but I wonder what kind of linking problem is happening. When searching that error message in conjunction with PhraseExpress I only get three results of which note are useful.

So, did anyone experience this before or know what is going on? What can I do to debug this?

[image]

This doesn't look good, however, these files are on my system.

But I guess that Windows 8 is kinda game breaking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what do we do when a new OS is game breaking?

**Compatibility mode with the latest service pack of Windows 7 seems to work just fine.**